# Woocommerce Mini Cart Poduct description is not affected by CSS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

So my Woocommerce mini cart has text which overflows the container, the text which overflows is the product name, in this case it is "SFD1 SATIN LACQUERED RUSTIC" in the pic below

[image: ,]

I can't seem to be able to change the style of the product title, word-wrap would be great! But if I add this to the stylesheet it doesn't affect the

Using Chrome Dev tools there seems to be no styling on the product name - I can' even edit the styling in Dev tools:-

[image: inspecting the mini cart in Chrome developer tools]

I've included a code snippet of woocommerce> cart> min-cart.php

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

 do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

<ul class="woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo esc_attr( $args['list_class'] ); ?>">
    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
                <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                        '<a href="%s" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                        __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                        esc_attr( $product_id ),
                        esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
                        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                    ), $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <?php if ( empty( $product_permalink ) ) : ?>
                        <?php echo $thumbnail . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                    <?php else : ?>

                    // added class woocommerce_wr to stop spillage
                        <a class = "woocommerce_wr" href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                            <?php echo $thumbnail . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents' );
    ?>
</ul>

<p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total"><strong><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

<p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons buttons"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' ); ?></p>
```

```
<p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must select the tag containing the product name. In this case the `<a>` tag. If you apply styles to the enclosing `<a>` tag the product name styles will update.